# Create Databases Dynamically with Google Cloud SQL and PHP

Tags: php, sql, google-app-engine, mysqli, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to have a database created for each user that signs up for my web app. This database will be based on a template to store their data.

The problem I'm running into is that `Google Could SQL` doesn't seem to be creating the Database via `PHP` and `MySQL` queries.

Connecting to the Instance works fine and triggers no errors based on this code:

```
//CLOUD SQL CONNECTION FOR SUBSCRIPTIONS
        $hostname = details;
        $username = details;
        $password = details;

        $port = details;
        $socket = details;

        $connection = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $port, $socket);

        // Check Connection
        if($connection->connect_error) {
            trigger_error('Connection failed: ' . $connection->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR);
        }
```

However, when I go to create a simple database, `mysqli` fails without an error...:

```
//Create Database
        $username = 'account';
        $database = 'sub_'. $username .'_db';

        $query = "CREATE DATABASE  IF NOT EXISTS `{$database}`;";

        if(mysqli_query($connection, $query)) {
            echo "Database my_db created successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error creating database: " . mysqli_error($connection);
        }
```

The output of this is simply: `Error creating database:`

Am I missing something? How do I create a `database` in a `Cloud SQL` instance via `PHP`? Thanks for any input.

Can anyone confirm that this can actually be done on GAE PHP and Cloud SQL?

Comment: Probably the user doesn't have permissions to create the DB. Have you tried to do it through a connection to the instance with MySQL client?

Comment: What happens if you run a query that does not create a database? For example "SELECT 1;"?

Comment: The same thing happens with `SELECT 1;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the `$connection` variable was actually `NULL` despite not throwing an error. This worked for me though:

I connected to an existing `database`:

```
//CLOUD SQL CONNECTION FOR SUBSCRIPTIONS
        $hostname = details;
        $username = details;
        $password = details;
        $db = details;
        $port = details;
        $socket = details;

        $connection = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $db, $port, $socket);

        // Check Connection
        if($connection->connect_error) {
            trigger_error('Connection failed: ' . $connection->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR);
        }
```

Then I created a new `database`:

```
//Create Database
        $username = 'account';
        $database = 'sub_'. $username .'_db';

        $query = "CREATE DATABASE  IF NOT EXISTS `{$database}`;";

        if(mysqli_query($connection, $query)) {
            echo "Database my_db created successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error creating database: " . mysqli_error($connection);
        }
```

Then used `mysqli_select_db()` to select the newly created `database`.

```
//Select Newly Created DB
            mysqli_select_db($connection, $database);
```